# Issue using MaximumLikelihoodEstimator.estimate_cpd() from pgmpy when using dataframe with tuples as columns names as parameter

Tags: python, pgmpy

When I use a dataframe with only text as columns names the code works fine. Now I need to use a dataframe with tuples as columns names as parameter for **MaximumLikelihoodEstimator.estimate_cpd()** method from **pgmpy.estimators**, but it raises the ***KeyError: "None of [Index(['Consumption', 0], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"***

I was trying to use the **MaximumLikelihoodEstimator.estimate_cpd()** on a standard Bayesian network to generate the cpds for an Dynamic Bayesian Netwok (DBN) since the said method is not implemented yet for DBNs. So I want to generate a cpd table with the names used on DBNs, that are tuples.

The altered Dataframe **categorical_energy_production** is similar to this example table:

|  | ('Consumption', 0) | ('Production', 0) | ('Nuclear', 0) | ('Oil and Gas', 0) | ('Hydroelectric', 0) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DateTime |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | high | low | low | high | low |
| 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | high | high | low | high | high |

Code:

```
energy_production_model = BayesianNetwork([(('Nuclear', 0),('Production', 0)),
                                           (('Oil and Gas', 0),('Production', 0)),
                                           (('Hydroelectric', 0),('Production', 0))]) #This works

cpd_production = MaximumLikelihoodEstimator(energy_production_model, categorical_energy_production).estimate_cpd(('Production', 0))

# ^ This raises the error KeyError: "None of [Index(['Consumption', 0], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```